# Input Rich HTML in a Sandboxed Visual Web Part

Tags: development, jquery, html, sandbox-solution

I'm trying to build a styled web part for adding list items to a list, and I cannot for the life of me find a good control for adding a Rich HTML editor.

Has anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Telerik RAD Editor: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-overview.html